# How to calculate the voltage drop in this case?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework, voltage, superposition

I started with the superposition principle.
For Vcc, Ib is open circuit and Eg is shorted. I got that the voltage drop due to Vcc is 10000/3 V.
For Ib, Eg is shorted as well as Vcc. Since Ib is dc then the inductor is also shorted, correct? I got that the voltage drop due to Ib is 1/3 V.  Is it right?

But I am not sure how to proceed about the Eg, how to calculate the equivalent voltage in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough, this is a question asked on interviews as well! So if you're a student, definitely pay attention to these problems. They will come in handy when applying for a job or an internship.

That being said, I don't have a lot of time at the moment to solve the problem (maybe I'll do it later), but I'll point you in the right direction. Always simplify your problem and don't get intimidated voltage sources with non-dc components. At the end of the day if we forget the sine function of the supply and we just call it V1, then your simplified circuit looks like this:

[image]

Then the problem is simplified by KCL. We know that the voltage Vx is nothing more than Ix*R. So applying KCL we have that I0+I1=Ix+X2.

[image]